# how to construct a compass sass with high efficiency

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I am a beginer of compass sass,I want to know how to how to construct a compass sass project with high efficiency. Is there any existed compass sass framework in github . Or can any experienced developer suggest me how to write a good compass sass project .Thank you very much.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Various frameworks have been ported to work with Compass, but I don't recommend them. The common CSS frameworks are built to be one-size-fits-all, because that's the best you can do with a pre-set list of CSS classes. With Sass you can build much more targeted and flexible tools, and then combine them all in unique ways using Compass.

There are several already-answered SO questions that are relevant to what you are asking:

- [Using Compass/Sass with another CSS framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309773/using-compass-sass-with-another-css-framework/12312041#12312041) for more on frameworks.
- [SASS: Extending Classess vs Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325610/sass-extending-classess-vs-variables/12327228#12327228) for more on using `@extends`.
- [Structuring CSS (SASS, LESS) files by elements, by function and by media queries: 3D code structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12822810/structuring-css-sass-less-files-by-elements-by-function-and-by-media-queries/12824576#12824576) for more on organizing your code.

Keep mixins and silent classes (like `%mgb5`) as simple as possible without losing meaning. It's a good rule for classes in general. `nav` is short and still easy to understand, `mgb5` is not as much. The same rule can guide you inside the mixin/class. If you only have one property, the mixin/class may not mean much. If you have thirty, it's probably trying to do carry too much meaning. Split larger mixins/classes into smaller ones for more flexibility, as long as each one represents a distinct and meaningful action.

The same basic guidelines apply for static css vs. variables. If any rule has a purpose that isn't clear in the plain css, then it should become part of a mixin, function, or variable that gives it the desired meaning. If `18px` is just a size that seems good to you for now, `18px` is just fine. But if `18px` is part of a set scale of sizes, or has a specific purpose, name it: `$large: 18px;` or `$gutter-width: 18px;`.

Comment: Thank you for your exhaustive answer.Great help.