# how to translate similar codes to a function in compass sass function?

Tags: sass

I want to add some common vars in my scss file, such as mgb10 for margin-bottom:10px; pdl20 for padding-left:20px; 
my method is very stupid. how to improve my code using a sass function.
[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of those extend classes?  You can't "fix" them without knowing how they are intended to be used.

Comment: I think it would be easier to just using the margin shorthand: `margin: 0 5px 15px 20px`, etc

Comment: @bookcasey My impression is that they don't understand the difference between `@extend` and `@include` and why it matters for the output (see their previous [closed] question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13282112/how-to-construct-a-compass-sass-with-high-efficiency).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bookcasey gave a great answer to the OP's question, but I'm not convinced the right question was asked.  Here's the problem with `@extend` in the scenario you've drawn out with your example code and why it probably isn't the right choice.

Let's start with these little guys here, they look like ones we are likely to use pretty often:

```
%mgt10 { margin-top: 10px }
%mgb10 { margin-bottom: 10px }
%mgl10 { margin-left: 10px }
%mgr10 { margin-right: 10px }
```

We start coding along and end up using them a lot:

```
.body { @extend %mgt10; @extend %mgb10; @extend %mgr10; @extend %mgl10; font: 12px/1.4 sans-serif }

.error { @extend %mgt10; color: red; padding: 10px; }

.cool-button { @extend %mgt10; border: 1px solid }

hr.awesome { @extend %mgt10; color: blue }
```

This is what our short Sass file will generate (316 bytes):

```
.body, .error, .cool-button, hr.awesome {
  margin-top: 10px; }

.body {
  margin-bottom: 10px; }

.body {
  margin-left: 10px; }

.body {
  margin-right: 10px; }

.body {
  font: 12px/1.4 sans-serif; }

.error {
  color: red;
  padding: 10px; }

.cool-button {
  border: 1px solid; }

hr.awesome {
  color: blue; }
```

You wouldn't actually write your CSS that way, would you?  `@extend` is working against you in this case because it is generating far more selectors than you actually need (and it only gets worse the more selectors you have extending any given class and the fewer the number of lines in said class being extended -- imagine 30 selectors extending `%mgt10`, how about 50?).  You've taken DRY to the extreme and as a result, you've given up readability on the Sass side and conciseness on the CSS side.

Let's try another route:

```
$default-gutter-size: 5px;

@function gutter($width, $size: $default-gutter-size) {
    @return $width * $size;
}

.body { margin: gutter(2); font: 12px/1.4 sans-serif }

.error { margin-top: gutter(2); color: red; padding: gutter(2); }

.cool-button { margin-top: gutter(2); border: 1px solid }

hr.awesome { margin-top: gutter(2); color: blue }
```

We get essentially the same CSS, but without all of the extra selectors and we still have the ability to use shorthand (as an added bonus, we can use our function on things that aren't margins if we really want) (228 bytes):

```
.body {
  margin: 10px;
  font: 12px/1.4 sans-serif; }

.error {
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: red;
  padding: 10px; }

.cool-button {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid; }

hr.awesome {
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: blue; }
```

Don't get me wrong, `@extend` is great, but it is best used for extending classes with a fair number of attributes, not just 1 or 2.  Part of using a CSS Preprocessor is knowing when to use which feature to get the best result.

Comment: very great. you just correct my wrong idea. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Sass mixin (you can change it to Scss) that uses the `@for` directive to generate all the placeholder selectors:

```
=shorthander($property: margin, $shorthand: mg)
  @for $i from 0 through 4
    $multiple: $i*5
    %#{$shorthand}#{$multiple}
      #{$property}: $multiple*1px

+shorthander()
+shorthander(margin-top, mgt)
+shorthander(margin-right, mgr)
+shorthander(margin-bottom, mgb)
+shorthander(margin-left, mgl)

div
  @extend %mgt20
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dpcBl)