# How do I implement OOCSS' spacing module in SCSS?

Tags: css, sass, mixins

I've got a SCSS-based layout in which I want to use the [spacing module from OOCSS](https://github.com/stubbornella/oocss/blob/master/core/spacing/space.css).

The OOCSS module is pure CSS - `ptl`, for example, stands for `padding-top: large`, where large is a defined value (by default 20px).

I'd like to enhance it with SCSS. So far I've been able to replace the fixed values with SCSS variables, so I can change the values in one place if I want to (I don't want to):

```
$spacing-small: 5px;
$spacing-medium: 10px;
$spacing-large: 20px;
...
.pts,.pvs,.pas{padding-top:$spacing-small !important}
```

Now I'd like to be able to use `ptn`,`pvs`, etc. as mixins, so I can do this:

```
.client-name {
  @include spacing-pvs; // this has the same padding properties as pvs
}
```

I'm flexible in the syntax, but that's the functionality I'd be interested in having.

The only way I can think of for doing this is manually defining every single mixin:

```
@mixin spacing-pvs {
  padding-top: $spacing-small !important;
  padding-bottom: $spacing-small !important;
}
.pvs { @include spacing-pvs; }
```

But there are around 56 styles/mixins. Doing each one individually like this would be pain to write and to maintain.

Is there a better way to do this in SASS/SCSS?

Comment: Wow, people actually write CSS like that?  That's the most painful thing I can think of.  Plus, it overuses/abuses `!important`.  It's pretty much the poster child for "why OOCSS is bad".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not using mixins at all. Instead, I left the CSS rules as they were, and I used this less documented feature called [`@extend`](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extend). Behold!:

```
.client-name {
  @extend .pvs; // this has the same padding properties as .pvs
}
```

Comment: See this answer for why this solution is a very bad idea:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284945/how-to-translate-similar-codes-to-a-function-in-compass-sass-funtion/13297956#13297956

Comment: Well, I don't think that applies on this case. I won't have the css classes extended in all my rules as you are showing in your answer. Maybe in 5 or 10 places (out of a hundred). The extra 10-20 lines of generated CSS don't concern me.

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient mixin would be like this (you'll need a similar mixin for padding, or add an extra argument to switch between margin/padding):

```
@mixin marginify($t: null, $r: null, $b: null, $l: null) {
    margin-top: $t;
    margin-right: $r;
    margin-bottom: $b;
    margin-left: $l;
}

.test {
    @include marginify($t: 10px, $b: 10px);
    color: green;
}
```

Which generates this:

```
.test {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: green;
}
```

The `null` (available in Sass 3.2+) is doing its magic here:  if a variable is `null`, then it doesn't generate a property for it.  However, you have to give up the use of `!important` (most people would argue that you should only use it as a last resort anyway).  Reliance on this mixin is going to introduce a fair bit of bloat because the longhand form is always used over the shorthand (`margin: 10px 0`), so you'll need to use it responsibly or write a more powerful mixin that will generate the shorthand if appropriate.

That said, using a mixin for this purpose (adding margins) does reduce readability in your code.  Before I looked at the entire source, the names made no sense.  There's a lot to be said about the readability of vanilla CSS.  The `marginify` mixin isn't really a reusable pattern like a `clearfix` or `inline-menu` mixin might be:  writing a mixin isn't just about saving keystrokes.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I think I found a simpler solution (see my answer), but +1 for your effort and the `null` trick, which I didn't know!