# Splitting up a list of variables in Sass

Tags: variables, loops, sass

In Sass is there a way to split up a list of variables / classes with hyphens?
It's a fuzzy question title so it's probably best I show what I'm trying to achieve.

In the below example I'm trying to create some utility classes that I can apply to HTML elements to help with vertical rhythm.

For example I may want to give an element a small margin that is consistent with my vertical rhythm strategy and so I'll add the class .m-t-s (which stands for margin-top-small).

I then want to output versions of those utility classes against for each media query I have for fine grain control e.g. I may want a class `.m-t-s-768` which will add a small top margin when there is a minimum viewport width of 768px.

I have achieved this below, but it is a very long-winded and repetitive way of doing it. Can anyone suggest a more concise way?

```
Variables
––––––––––
$mediaQueries-px:
640,
768,
1024
;

$s: 20px; /* FYI I've simplified these examples for the sake of demonstration, normally I use something like ($baseLineHeight / 1.5) + rem */
$m: 50px;
$l: 60px;

Creating the classes
–––––––––––––––––––––
.m-t-s {
  margin-top: $s;
}

/* Create versions for each defined media query */
@each $mediaQuery in $mediaQueries-px {
  @media screen and (min-width: ($mediaQuery / 16px)) {
    .m-t-s-#{$mediaQuery} {
      margin-top: $s;
    }
  }
}

.m-t-m {
  margin-top: $m;
}

/* Create versions for each defined media query */
@each $mediaQuery in $mediaQueries-px {
  @media screen and (min-width: ($mediaQuery / 16px)) {
    .m-t-m-#{$mediaQuery} {
      margin-top: $m;
    }
  }
}
```

This repeats for `.m-t-l` too (margin top large), and then it continues for padding classes (e.g. `.p-t-s` and so on), so it gets to be a pretty long list of utility classes.

Comment: So much presentation in your HTML.  Why would you do this?

Comment: I'm actually more likely for me to pull these classes into other semantic classes via @extend, but it is nice to have the option to use these on elements when needed. I wouldn't do this with other properties but margin and padding are much more permanent.

Comment: Using `@extend` for single properties can quickly spiral out of control (see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284945/how-to-translate-similar-codes-to-a-function-in-compass-sass-funtion/13297956)

Comment: Have you seen the vw and vh units?  http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units, http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: hmmm...I've heard of vm units but not sure whether they'll help me in getting consistent vertical rhythm. Thanks for you comments, I understand your concerns about extending single property selectors, but it's a very specific thing I'm trying to achieve and think it may be worth the overhead to be honest. I'm also still curious whether there is a neater way to do this in SASS, and if it get's out of control performance-wise I may re-assess if there's another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To programatically generate that output, you need another list and an inner loop:

```
$mediaQueries-px:
640,
768,
1024
;

$s: 20px;
$m: 50px;
$l: 60px;

$sizes: s $s, m $m, l $l;

@each $size in $sizes {
    .m-t-#{nth($size, 1)} {
      margin-top: nth($size, 2);
    }
}

@each $mediaQuery in $mediaQueries-px {
  @media screen and (min-width: ($mediaQuery / 16 * 1em)) { // modified for compilation purposes
    @each $size in $sizes {
        .m-t-#{nth($size, 1)}-#{$mediaQuery} {
          margin-top: nth($size, 2);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
.m-t-s {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.m-t-m {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.m-t-l {
  margin-top: 60px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .m-t-s-640 {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }

  .m-t-m-640 {
    margin-top: 50px;
  }

  .m-t-l-640 {
    margin-top: 60px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 48em) {
  .m-t-s-768 {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }

  .m-t-m-768 {
    margin-top: 50px;
  }

  .m-t-l-768 {
    margin-top: 60px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 64em) {
  .m-t-s-1024 {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }

  .m-t-m-1024 {
    margin-top: 50px;
  }

  .m-t-l-1024 {
    margin-top: 60px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ahh thanks so much cimmanon, that's brilliant. You have answered quite a few of my noob SASS questions recently and I'm very grateful.