# SCSS usage of extends

Tags: sass, extends

We have a lot of positioned elements and i was thinking about abstracting the patterns i found into some helper classes that can be used over and over.

```
.pos {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}

.pos--fixed  { position:fixed; }

.pos--bottom { top:    auto; }
.pos--top    { bottom: auto; }
.pos--left   { right:  auto; }
.pos--right  { left:   auto; }
```

Using the @extend feature i'd like to use it later in our modules like this:

```
.module__element1 {
  @extend .pos;
  @extend .pos--top;
}

.module__element2 {
  @extend .pos;
  @extend .pos--bottom;
}
```

Is this considered a good approach? I think it is, but my colleagues have doubts (that they couldn't really explain)

This is why i think it is:

- it's very unlikely that the pos-classes or the way we position elements will change
- yes, it produces more selectors in the final css-file but less code
- it makes the scss-source files easier to read & maintain.

I hope I get some input here instead of doubts only :)

Comment: Opinion based questions are frowned on around here.  Personally, I don't find that the use of extends makes the code any more readable.  You're only fooling yourself if you think this is getting you *less* code.  If you count the characters, `@extend .pos; @extend .pos--bottom;` is *more* code than `position: fixed; bottom: auto`.  See also: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/26003/mixin-extend-or-silent-class/27910#27910 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284945/how-to-translate-similar-codes-to-a-function-in-compass-sass-function/13297956#13297956

Comment: I don't mean less code in the scss file, i mean less code in the resulting css-file.

Comment: Right, you also get *more* code in the CSS file as the links I provided show.

Comment: position: fixed; bottom: auto; != position:fixed; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:auto;

But i'm seeing your point. .pos would be enough.