# SCSS value multiples

Tags: css, integer, sass

I am trying to do something with scss. I basically want it so I can have any margin for every 5px. So for example I can write m10 m15 m20 m25 etc... and it will create margin:10px; margin:15px; etc...

So far I have got:

```
@for $margin from 0 through 100 {
  .m#{$margin} { margin: 1px * $margin }
}
```

But this renders all numbers between the multiples of 5 which is not ideal. Is it possible to render margins for only the multiples of 5 up to 100?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Beware that you're not falling into this trap:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284945/how-to-translate-similar-codes-to-a-function-in-compass-sass-function

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
@for $margin from 0 through 100 {
  @if $margin % 5 == 0 {
    .m#{$margin} { margin: 1px * $margin }
  }
}
```

Hi think is what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Don't think in terms of the margin size you want when writing out your loop, but how many margins you need:

```
@for $margin from 0 through 20 {
  .m#{$margin * 5} { margin: 5px * $margin }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest another way, using [SASS mixins](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-6):

```
// Define a mixin to create custom margin width:
@mixin custom-margin($margin_width) {
  margin: $margin_width
}
```

Then you can create custom margins for any element:

```
h1   { @include custom-margin(10px); }
span { @include custom-margin(0); }
.box { @include custom-margin(5px); }
```